# Split a loop into smaller parts

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop, mathematical-optimization

I have a function inside a loop that takes a lot of resources and usually does not get completed unless the server is on low load.

How can I split it into smaller loops? When decreasing the value the function executes fine.

As an example, this works:

```
x = 10
for i = 0; i <= x; i++ 
{ 
 myfunction(i)
}
```

However, when increasing *x* to 100 the memory hogging function stops working.

How can one split 100 in chunks of 10 (i.e.) and run the loop 10 times?

I should be able to use any value, not only 100 or multiples of 10.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is your function asynchronous and you're having too many instances at once?  Is it opening and not closing resources?  Perhaps you could put a delay in after every 10 iterations?

```
x = 1000
for i = 0; i <= x; i++ 
{ 
 myfunction(i);
 if(i%10==0)
 {
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's asynchronous. Just one instance that works on *i*. A delay might not work since the resource is still open, but I can give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: If you're not in C#, you could put some sort of flag in place that tells you when your function is done and do a Thread.Sleep(1000) repeatedly until your flag indicates that 'myfunction(i)' has completed..

Answer (score 0):

If your task is asynchronous you can use worker thread pool technique.

Ex

You can create thread pool with 10 thread. 
First you assign 10 tasks to them. 
Whenever a task is finished you can assign remaining task to the given thread.

Comment: Different languages/frameworks use different constructs to handle such scenario.If you can provide your specific language I may provide specific solution.